# NSColorWell and Cocos2D Layer issue

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, layer, nscolor

I am tying to dynamically change my background color on the fly using an NSColorWell. I am using cocos2d framework for desktop.

I have a GLView that shows the cocos2d window and I have a NSColorwell off to the side. When I click on the color well color, I want the background to change to that color ‘on-the-fly’ so to speak.

I have all my variables in one class called settings. And my AppDeletgate has the IBActions for the NSColorWell. And the Cocos2D GLview lives in the HelloWorldLayer.

When ever I chose a color in the NSColorWell I get an exception thrown. Any idea why?

Forgive the code dump but I wanted you all to be able to see exactly what I was doing. I have tried many different methods of implementing this.

AppDelegate.h

```
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface AnimatorAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{
    NSWindow    *window_;
    MacGLView   *glView_;

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow    *window;
@property (assign) IBOutlet MacGLView   *glView;

- (IBAction)bgColorWell:(id)sender;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "HelloWorldLayer.h"
#import "Settings.h"

@implementation AnimatorAppDelegate

@synthesize window=window_, glView=glView_;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    CCDirectorMac *director = (CCDirectorMac*) [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    [director setDisplayFPS:YES];
    [director setOpenGLView:glView_];
    [director setResizeMode:kCCDirectorResize_AutoScale];
    [window_ setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:NO];
    [director runWithScene:[HelloWorldLayer scene]];
}

#pragma mark AppDelegate - IBActions

- (IBAction)toggleFullScreen: (id)sender
{
    CCDirectorMac *director = (CCDirectorMac*) [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    [director setFullScreen: ! [director isFullScreen] ];
}

- (IBAction)bgColorWell:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Color Well %@", [sender color]);
    HelloWorldLayer *layer = [[HelloWorldLayer alloc] init];
    [layer setBackgroundColorForLayer:[sender color]];
}

@end
```

Settings.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface Settings : NSObject {
    NSColor *_backgroundColor;
}

+ (Settings *) sharedSettings;

- (NSColor *) returnBackgroundColor;
- (void) setBackgroundColor : (NSColor *)c;
@end
```

Settings.m

```
#import "Settings.h"

@implementation Settings

static  Settings * _sharedSettings;

- (id) init {

    if (self =  [super init]){
//_backgroundColor = [NSColor colorWithDeviceRed:102/255.0f green:205/255.0f blue:170/255.0f alpha:1.0];
        _backgroundColor = [NSColor blueColor];
    }
    return self;
}

+ (Settings *) sharedSettings {
    if (!_sharedSettings) {
        _sharedSettings = [[Settings alloc] init];
    }

    return _sharedSettings;
}

- (NSColor *) returnBackgroundColor {
    return _backgroundColor;
}
- (void) setBackgroundColor : (NSColor *)c {

    _backgroundColor = c;
}

@end
```

HelloWorldLayer.h

```
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "Settings.h"

// HelloWorldLayer
@interface HelloWorldLayer : CCLayer
{
}

// returns a CCScene that contains the HelloWorldLayer as the only child
+(CCScene *) scene;

- (void) setBackgroundColorForLayer : (id) sender;

@end
```

HelloWorldLayer.m

```
// Import the interfaces
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "HelloWorldLayer.h"
#import  "Settings.h"

// HelloWorldLayer implementation
@implementation HelloWorldLayer

+(CCScene *) scene
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object.
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object.
    HelloWorldLayer *layer = [HelloWorldLayer node];

    // add layer as a child to scene
    [scene addChild: layer];

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}

// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
-(id) init
{
    // always call "super" init
    // Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super" return value
    if( (self=[super init])) {
        CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) setBackgroundColorForLayer : (id) sender {

    Settings *mySettings = [Settings sharedSettings];

    float red = [mySettings returnBackgroundColor].redComponent * 255;
    float green = [mySettings returnBackgroundColor].greenComponent * 255;
    float blue = [mySettings returnBackgroundColor].blueComponent * 255;

    CCLayerColor* colorLayer = [CCLayerColor layerWithColor:ccc4(red, green, blue, 255)];
    [self addChild:colorLayer z:0];

    NSLog(@"Red color: %f", red);
    NSLog(@"Green color: %f", green);
    NSLog(@"Blue color: %f", blue);

    //[self setBackgroundColorForLayer:sender];

    NSLog(@"This Background color is %@" , [mySettings returnBackgroundColor]);


}
```

Comment: what does the exception say? Where does it occur? Enable global exception breakpoint in Xcode.

Comment: After tinkering I found I was passing the wrong data type. I did finally add     
Settings *mySettings = [Settings sharedSettings];
[mySettings setBackgroundColor:[sender color]]; to my AppDelegate. However, the background color isn't changing. Am I doing something wrong? I know the correct color is beging passed to Settings, I NSLog'ged the output.